# Log-normal variance estimation

Tags: variance, estimation, lognormal-distribution

I have generated some log-normal sample data with python (I tried also with Wolfram Mathematica). Let's say with parameters $\mu = -14.6$ and $\sigma = 3.6$, but even with other parameters I observe the same thing.

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.random.lognormal(-14.6,3.6,1000000)
np.var(aa)

0.24445857538415491
```

While a log-normal with the same parameters should have a variance:
$V(X)=(e^{σ^2}−1)⋅e^{2μ+σ^2} \simeq 0.038$. I did also the same computation over the $100000$ independently generated variables $aa$, defined as before and still the value does not converge to the right variance as it should be, and it's around the value shown above. Indeed I can generate from 10000 to 1000000  or even more variables I don't see significant variations of the estimated variance.

I also computed the variance of the estimator and with this such a high size of the sample, the error should be much smaller than the error I found out.

I don't understand why, since in principle the variance estimator is unbiased and can be used for any distribution.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think I understood the problem. The thing is that when I generate the sample I would need a really huge amount of data to have values that are representative of the tail because they have a very small probability. Usually (for example for Gaussians) this is not a problem but for a log-normal distribution (or I think any highly non symmetric distribution) these values are crucial for the computation of the variance.